# How can I Get the number of defined Enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have 3 Enum. MyEnumA, MyEnumB, MyEnumC.

I need to determines how many Enum in class or namespace.

The code should return 3.

```
enum MyEnumA{ }
enum MyEnumB{ }
enum MyEnumC{ }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use reflection to get the types from your assembly. I'm including a console app that will get all the enum types in the executing assembly, count them, and print the proper value. Note that this may change depending on the framework such as in UWP getting types (`GetTypes()`) is just a little different. Overall I think this console app example answers your question.

**Simple Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var enumsInAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                          .GetTypes()
                                          .Where(type => type.IsEnum);

            Console.WriteLine(enumsInAssembly.Count());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    enum MyEnumA { }
    enum MyEnumB { }
    enum MyEnumC { }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
3
```

Here is a more in depth version of the same example app that will sort of help you navigate through namespaces and classes (as pointed out in a comment you may want to search a particular namespace or class.)  Looking at this example should help you write or understand how to write the proper logic you require to get the results you need.  Either way, just know everything you need when searching assemblies for types, attributes, modifiers, ETC; is found using reflection.

**Deeper Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                        .GetTypes()
                                        .OrderBy(type => type.Name);

            var namespacesInAssembly = assemblyTypes.Select(type => type.Namespace)
                                                    .Distinct()
                                                    .OrderBy(name => name);

            var enumsInAssembly = assemblyTypes.Where(type => type.IsEnum)
                                               .OrderBy(type => type.Name); ;

            var enumsInNamespaceB = enumsInAssembly.Where(@enum => @enum.Namespace.EndsWith(nameof(NamespaceB)))
                                                   .OrderBy(type => type.Name); ;

            var enumsInClassC = assemblyTypes.Where(type => type.IsClass)
                                             .Where(type => type.Name == nameof(NamespaceC.ClassC))
                                             .SelectMany(type => type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
                                             .Where(type => type.IsEnum)
                                             .OrderBy(type => type.Name);

            foreach (var @namespace in namespacesInAssembly)
                Console.WriteLine($"Namespace found: {@namespace}");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Enums in Assembly: {enumsInAssembly.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Enums in Namespace B: {enumsInNamespaceB.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Enums in Class C: {enumsInClassC.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var x in enumsInClassC)
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    namespace NamespaceA
    {
        enum MyEnumA { }
    }

    namespace NamespaceB
    {
        enum MyEnumB { }
    }

    namespace NamespaceC
    {
        public class ClassC
        {
            enum MyEnumC { }
            enum MyEnumD { }
        }
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Namespace found: Question_Answer_Console_App
Namespace found: Question_Answer_Console_App.NamespaceA
Namespace found: Question_Answer_Console_App.NamespaceB
Namespace found: Question_Answer_Console_App.NamespaceC

Enums in Assembly: 4

Enums in Namespace B: 1

Enums in Class C: 2

MyEnumC
MyEnumD
```

Comment: will it count in entire Assembly? BTW, OP is clear if wants all enum number in particular file or namespace or assembly!

Comment: @Amit Good call Amit.. I've updated the answer with a second example and explanation using a more in depth version of reflection to also show navigating namespaces and classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it up in a generic method to target a `class`, or `assembly` or a `namespace`

**Example**

```
  private static int GetEnumCountFromClass<T>()
  {
    return typeof(T).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
         .Count(x => x.IsEnum);
  }

  private static int GetEnumFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace = null)
  {
     assembly = assembly ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
     var types = assembly.GetTypes().AsEnumerable();

     if (nameSpace != null)
     {
        types = types.Where(x => x.Namespace == nameSpace);
     }
     return types.Count(x => x.IsEnum);

  }
```

**Usage**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enum Count from class : " + GetEnumCountFromClass<Program>());
   Console.WriteLine("Enum Count from assembly : " + GetEnumFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](http://ttps://dotnetfiddle.net/pSCGqb)

---

[Type.GetNestedTypes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the types nested within the current Type.

[BindingFlags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies flags that control binding and the way in which the search
>   for members and types is conducted by reflection.

[Assembly.GetTypes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the types defined in this assembly.